# Publishing status: Rejected - Google play store app review

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

I am facing the below issue, I have previously declared the permissions but since i do not need the permissions any more, I removed the permissions from the manifest file and uploaded the new version, but still it is referring to older declaration and continuously getting rejected in the review.

Tried the answers provided in the other blogs, but no luck so far.

Hi Developers ....,

Publishing Status
Publishing status: Rejected
After review, your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
Issue: Violation of Permissions policy
After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):
Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app
You declared Device Automation as the core functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that your app does not match the declared use case(s). Learn more about permitted uses and exceptions.
Please either:
• Make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements of the declared core functionality or,
• Select a use case that matches your app’s functionality

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating the version number? For example: 1.0.1?

Comment: @TrayDenney, I have released more than 20 versions, but still i am getting this error.

Comment: In your photo it shows 20.aab(1.0.0). I believe even if you were to go to 21.aab(1.0.0) it would still see it as version 1.0.0. If you haven't changed the actual version in the pubspec.yaml file to 1.0.1+20, then I would try that. 

Other than that, you might try creating a new app within google play console with updated permissions.

Comment: Have you put the new version in all tracks?

Comment: @user14678216
As you suggested, after updating the new version in all the tracks with removed permissions, the error got resolved.